# Using C# telegram.bot to detect a new message in a telegram channel

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

I want a program which will constantly check a telegram channel, and if a new message is sent, it should take that message as input to do something else.

I have a Telegram bot ( with telegram.bot v19 ) and I set this bot as admin of a channel. But, when a new message is sent to the channel by anther admin, no message bot could get with OnMessage method.

```
TelegramBotClient bot = new Telegram.Bot.TelegramBotClient(myBotToken);
start_bot();

 public async Task start_bot()
   {
    var token = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var canceltoken = token.Token;
    var option = new Telegram.Bot.Polling.ReceiverOptions { AllowedUpdates = { } };
    await bot.ReceiveAsync(OnMessage, OnError, option, canceltoken);
   }

 public async Task OnMessage(ITelegramBotClient bot_, Update update, CancellationToken canceltoken)
        {...}

 public async Task OnError(ITelegramBotClient bot_, Exception e, CancellationToken canceltoken)
        {...}
```

like this code in telethon

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events

client = TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash)

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats = [123123]))
async def handler(event):
    print("Event Occured")
    print(event.raw_text)

client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
```